# Where to rollback a transaction in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, pdo

my problem is , i have a database design from this link [is my database overdesigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305825/is-my-database-overdesigned)

edit* ok maybe useing transaction ? but where should i put the rollback if it fails ?

```
 $dbConnect->beginTransaction();
 $RegisterInsert = $dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO companies (
    `name`, `address`, `email`, `phone`, `link`, `verified`) VALUES (
    :name, :address, :email, :phone, :link, :verified)");
    $RegisterInsert->execute($RegisterData);

    $RegisterData2['CID'] = $dbConnect->lastInsertId();  

    $RegisterInsert = $dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO users_companies (
    `UID`, `CID`, `role`) VALUES (
    :UID, :CID, :role)");
    $RegisterInsert->execute($RegisterData2);
    $dbConnect->commit();
```

where should i put the rollback ?

Thanks

Comment: yup im a bit confused should i do transactions thing ? ( i never used it ) or just do like this, or maybe some joining ? or others that may i have missed, thanks pascal to leave a comment :)

Comment: possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167853/insert-entries-in-multiple-tables-in-php,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449132/run-mysql-insert-query-multiple-times-insert-values-into-multiple-tables,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225024/mysql-insert-to-multiple-tables-relational,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582834/php-mysql-inserting-data-to-multiple-tables

Comment: yes i know that, i dont know the best title for this problem, please edit it.

Comment: You should always use transactions with appropriate error handling to ensure that your database remains consistent (what happens if your second insert fails because of insufficient disk space, or because MySQL has crashed), but not all MySQL table types support the use of transactions... e.g. MyISAM doesn't, InnoDB does.

Comment: @mark thanks im learning it right now.

Comment: @mark updated, where should i put the rollback then ?

Comment: Put in an error trap after the first $RegisterInsert->execute and rollback on error, else do your $dbConnect->lastInsertId(); and second $RegisterInsert->execute with a second error trap after that and rollback on error, else commit

Comment: ok can you give me an example ?, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329622/how-can-i-implement-commit-rollback-for-mysql-in-php please take a look here, it says that commit does an rollback if it fails ? so we dont have to put an rollback or a error trap is that true ? thanks

Comment: Setting autoCommit to false should force a rollback at the end of your transaction unless you explicitly commit.... I don't know if commit does an automatic rollback if it fails. I prefer to make all my commits and rollbacks explicit in the code so that there's no misunderstanding when another developer looks at it.

Comment: good point there mark :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A transaction should end with either a `rollback()` or a `commit()`, (only one of them)

Its usually used with an `if...else` statement as logically only one of them should be executed.

```
$dbConnect->beginTransaction();

//somecode
//$dbConnect->execute( $someInsert );
//some more code
//$result = $dbConnect->execute( $someSelect );
//$nextRow = $result->fetchRow();

//either commit or rollback!
if( $someResultCheck == true )
    $dbConnect->commit();
else
    $dbConnect->rollback();
```

Transactions are usually used when there is a complex logic involved with queries.

In case you are using MySQL, make sure you are not using MyISAM engine for tables, as it doesn't support transactions.

Comment: Your code isn't guaranteed to automatically rollback unless autoCommit is set to false

Comment: ok so were we should do an $someResultCheck ?, on RegisterInsert ? am i right ?

Comment: @kaskus : Right. You only want to commit when both the inserts are successfully executed.So you will have to do `$someResultCheck = $RegisterInsert->execute($stmt);`.

Comment: @mark : autoCommit only matters for statements outside a transaction, where individual statements are wrapped inside a transaction. When you manually begin a transaction, it doesn't apply inside that.

Comment: @Kalyan - Thanks for the clarification. As I said elsewhere, I always code explicit transaction starts and commits/rollbacks because there'll never be any misunderstandings then with other developers reading the code

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you know that the transaction as a whole is going to fail then you should rollback what you've done so far and not try any further updates - so in pseudo-code:

```
 function do_updates(array updates)
 { 
    PDO->beginTransaction();
    foreach (updates as statement) {
       run statement
       if failed {
         PDO->rollback(); 
         return false;
       }
    }
    return PDO->commit();
```

HTH

C.